# Translating an English adverbial present participle into German

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clause

> In addition, the CNN cable network has subscribers in about 150 countries and territories, further increasing the world’s contact with the English language.

Should the text after the comma be translated using a Partizip I or using a subordinate clause starting with *was?*

My German is not good enough to for a good translation, and I am not after a help with that. Rather, I’d like to know which of these two grammar structures is better:

> ... Abonnenten in ungefähr 150 Ländern und Territorien, was weltweit die Kontakt mit der englischen Sprache weiter erhöht
>
> ... Abonnenten in ungefähr 150 Ländern und Territorien, die weltweite Kontakt mit der englischen Sprache weiter erhöhend.

I want to again stress (because I hope not to be put on hold for off topic) that I am not after a translation, only an indication of which is better grammatically; specifically, whether the second one is even possible.

Comment: There's no present continuous in German. Your second translation is wrong, unfortunately. Sentences with continuous forms should normally be ripped apart into separate main closes or clauses connected with "und". *...hat Abonnenten in 150 Ländern...und erleichtert so den Kontakt mit der...*

Comment: That's precisely the sort of answer I was after. Thank you very much.

Comment: ... hat Abonnenten in 150 Ländern, welche den weltweiten Kontakt mit der englischen Sprache erhöhen.

Also so, würde ich das übersetzen.

@tofro: wie kommst du dort auf *erleichtern*?

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 Ich finde, dass man einen *Kontakt* nicht *erhöhen* kann.

Comment: Wenn der Kontakt zu 3 Leuten besteht und man dann den Kontakt auf mit 10 Leuten erhöht? ;)

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 Wenn du eine Gruppe mit 3 schwangeren Frauen und eine andere mit 10 hast - Ist die zweite Gruppe dann *erhöht schwanger*?

Comment: @tofro: hab ich das so geschrieben?
Ich schrieb, dass der Kontakt erhöhrt ist, nicht die Schwangerschaft, respektive die persönlichen Eigenschaften. Du vergleichst hier Äpfel mit Birnen.

Wenn ich 3 Freunde habe und meine Freundeszahl auf 10 erhöhe, habe ich einen erhöhten sozialen Kontakt.

Comment: @tofro: Nachtrag: unter *erhöhen* steht im Duden bei BEDEUTUNGSÜBERSICHT im Punkt 2a **steigern; vermehren, verstärken** .... hier ist erhöhen im Sinne von *vermehren* gebraucht
LG

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 In meiner Welt ist eben Kontakt nix, was man erhöhen kann - genausowenig wie Schwangerschaft. Das hat man entweder, oder man hat es nicht - Das hat für mich nichts Graduelles.

Comment: @tofro: Also hast du zu Frfeunden nur Kontakt. Egal wie oft. 
Wenn du Freunde dreimal die Woche siehst, ist der Kontakt nicht höher als dann, wenn du diese Freunde nur einmal die Woche siehst?
LG

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the original sentence is weakly phrased, so any translation is either equally weak or must more deviate from the original.

> ... hat Abonnenten in 150 Ländern, was den weltweiten Kontakt mit der englischen Sprache verbessert.

would be quite close.

I agree with @tofro, however, that contact either exists or does not. One can increase the number of persons you contact, the frequency or the intensity but not the contact itself.

In my opinion the intention behind the sentence is more

> ... hat Abonnenten in 150 Ländern und ist dadurch Botschafter für die englische Sprache.

(... has subscribers and therefore serves as an ambassador of English language)

Comment: "I agree with @tofro, however, that contact either exists or does not. One can increase the number of persons you contact, the frequency or the intensity but not the contact itself." - that may be true for the German verb *erhöhen*, but if I am not mistaken, *increase* can very well have the meaning of *intensify*, which makes more sense here and could be translated as *intensivieren* or *verstärken*. Might be an interesting question for [elu.se], though.

Answer (score 0):

> ... hat Abonnenten in 150 Ländern, welche den weltweiten Kontakt mit
>   der englischen Sprache erhöhen.

so würde die Übersetzung meinem Wissenstand entsprechen.

Es kann gerne darüber diskutiert werden und bei einem überzeugenden Argument würde ich diese Antwort auch bearbeiten.